# GWT fileUploader HTTP ERROR: 404

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

i keep having **HTTP ERROR: 404_Problem accessing /Gwtuploader.html. Reason:_notfound**
when running my application on development mode. which im intending to upload to google_appengine later.

my console shows the following:

```
    Initializing App Engine server
Aug 05, 2014 12:13:16 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\user\workspace\gwtuploader\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Aug 05, 2014 12:13:16 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\user\workspace\gwtuploader\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Aug 05, 2014 12:13:16 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Dev\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.7\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.7\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Users\user\workspace\gwtuploader\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
Aug 05, 2014 12:13:16 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Aug 05, 2014 12:13:16 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
Aug 05, 2014 12:13:17 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed uploadServlet: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Servlet
Aug 05, 2014 12:13:17 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@2f81fbd2{/,C:\Users\user\workspace\gwtuploader\war}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Servlet
Aug 05, 2014 12:13:17 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@6907e6cb: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Servlet
Aug 05, 2014 12:13:17 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Servlet
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerClassLoader.loadClass(DevAppServerClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:175)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:216)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:254)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:288)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:522)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1104)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)

Aug 05, 2014 12:13:17 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
Aug 05, 2014 12:13:17 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8888/
Aug 05, 2014 12:13:17 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
Aug 05, 2014 12:13:17 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

and my files are as follow:

**uoloaderservlet.java file**

```
package gwtuploader.mygwt.server;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;

import gwtupload.server.UploadAction;
import gwtupload.server.exceptions.UploadActionException;
import gwtupload.shared.UConsts;

public class uploaderservlet extends UploadAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      Hashtable<String, String> receivedContentTypes = new Hashtable<String, String>();


      Hashtable<String, File> receivedFiles = new Hashtable<String, File>();


      public String executeAction(HttpServletRequest request, List<FileItem> sessionFiles) throws UploadActionException {
            String response = "";
            for (FileItem item : sessionFiles) {
              if (false == item.isFormField()) {
                try {
                  /// Create a new file based on the remote file name in the client
                  // String saveName = item.getName().replaceAll("[\\\\/><\\|\\s\"'{}()\\[\\]]+", "_");
                  // File file =new File("/tmp/" + saveName);

                  /// Create a temporary file placed in /tmp (only works in unix)
                  // File file = File.createTempFile("upload-", ".bin", new File("/tmp"));

                  /// Create a temporary file placed in the default system temp folder
                  File file = File.createTempFile("upload-", ".bin");
                  item.write(file);

                  /// Save a list with the received files
                  receivedFiles.put(item.getFieldName(), file);
                  receivedContentTypes.put(item.getFieldName(), item.getContentType());

                  /// Send a customized message to the client.
                  response += "File saved as " + file.getAbsolutePath();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                  throw new UploadActionException(e);
                }
              }
            }

            /// Remove files from session because we have a copy of them
            removeSessionFileItems(request);

            /// Send your customized message to the client.
            return response;
          }

          /**
           * Get the content of an uploaded file.
           */
          @Override
          public void getUploadedFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            String fieldName = request.getParameter(UConsts.PARAM_SHOW);
            File f = receivedFiles.get(fieldName);
            if (f != null) {
              response.setContentType(receivedContentTypes.get(fieldName));
              FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
              copyFromInputStreamToOutputStream(is, response.getOutputStream());
            } else {
              renderXmlResponse(request, response,ERROR_ITEM_NOT_FOUND);
           }
          }

          /**
           * Remove a file when the user sends a delete request.
           */
          @Override
          public void removeItem(HttpServletRequest request, String fieldName)  throws UploadActionException {
            File file = receivedFiles.get(fieldName);
            receivedFiles.remove(fieldName);
            receivedContentTypes.remove(fieldName);
            if (file != null) {
              file.delete();
            }
          }}
```

**GWTuploader.java** file

```
package gwtuploader.mygwt.client;

import gwtupload.client.IFileInput.FileInputType;
import gwtupload.client.IUploadStatus.Status;
import gwtupload.client.IUploader;
import gwtupload.client.IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler;
import gwtupload.client.ModalUploadStatus;
import gwtupload.client.SingleUploader;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class Gwtuploader implements EntryPoint {


    Button dou = new Button("Do Upload");

    FlowPanel flow = new FlowPanel();

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        SingleUploader uploader = new SingleUploader(FileInputType.LABEL, new ModalUploadStatus(), dou);
        //uploader.setServletPath("dou.file");
        flow.add(uploader);
        RootPanel.get().add(flow);
        uploader.addOnFinishUploadHandler(new uploaderOnFinishUploaderHandler());

    }


    private class uploaderOnFinishUploaderHandler implements OnFinishUploaderHandler{

        @Override
        public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
             if (uploader.getStatus() == Status.SUCCESS) {
                  Window.alert("Server response: \n" + uploader.getServerResponse());
                  uploader.reset();     
             }
        }

    }
}
```

**web.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <!-- Servlets -->

  <context-param>
    <!-- max size of the upload request -->
    <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
    <param-value>3145728</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <!-- Useful in development mode to slow down the uploads in fast networks.
         Put the number of milliseconds to sleep in each block received in the server.
         false or 0, means don't use slow uploads  -->
    <param-name>slowUploads</param-name>
    <param-value>200</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>gwtuploader.mygwt.server.uploaderservlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gupld</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Gwtuploader.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

and finally **GWTuploader.gwt.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.6.0//EN"
  "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.6.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='gwtuploader'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

  <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

  <inherits name="gwtupload.GWTUpload"/>
  <!-- Load dinamically predefined styles in the library when the application starts -->
  <stylesheet src="Upload.css"/>

  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='gwtuploader.mygwt.client.Gwtuploader'/>

  <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

  <!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
</module>
```

Comment: Do you have Gwtuploader.html in the war directory? How are you running it, from eclipse?

Comment: yes im running from eclipse , and do have Gwtuploader.html file in the war directory

Comment: Do you have gwt-servlet.jar in your classpath?

Comment: i have downloaded gwt-servlet/gwt-servlet-2.2.0.jar
But still giving same error ... is it for sure that gwt-uploader works with google appengine??

Comment: is it possibly caused by my eclipse EE ?? should i download the standard Kepler??

Comment: Yes, it works with appengine and as long as you have the GWT plugin installed and you started a normal Web Application Project it should work with eclipse EE too. Make sure you don't run eclipse luna though, as it's yet to be supported.

Comment: its Kepler.. however .. thanks alot for your help .. regards :)

Comment: No worries. You can join the irc channel #gwt at irc.freenode.net if you want further help!

Comment: Just going out on a limb here, but do you have the right JAR files not only on your classpath, but also in your `war/WEB-INF/lib` folder...? Had that trip me up just now, where I'd added a jar to my project's `lib` folder and added it to the classpath, but not as part of the WAR.